# Отправка файлов через браузер Tor

Tags: безопасность, tor

Ребята такой вопрос: если ты зарегистрировался на gmail анонимно через Tor, и загружаешь файлы в хранилище, они смогут узнать твой реальный IP?

Answer (score 0):

Через корреляционные атаки - определенно. И не только google, но всякий кто контролирует входной и выходной узел вашей цепочки.

Comment: а как сделать что бы не смогли найти реальный IP?

Comment: @Vong Не использовать сеть. Завести свой входной узел и стройть цепочку через него, может быть. Но тут я не уверен...

Comment: То есть если я захочу выложить на gmail "план теракта" то меня очень просто вычислят?

Comment: @Vong За вами уже выехали, я капу нажал ;-)

Comment: Ок,) а чисто теоретически что бы не заливать файл к примеру с "план теракта", а там создать документ Word и просто Ctrl+C -> Ctrl+V ? Узнают или нет?

Comment: И это не единственный способ. в js коде на сайте можно добавить обращение куда либо по UDP. А UDP через tor не ходит, он пойдет напрямую. Кроме того можно сделать любое уникальное доменное имя в любом запросе и отследить DNS с которого прийдет запрос - а это скорее всего будет ближайший к вам провайдер. И никто не мешает гуглу внедрять такие скрипты на свои страницы ...

Comment: @Mike для максимальной анонимности в Tor е можно отключить Js... Поможет?

Comment: И все же меня интересует ответ на вопрос "Чисто теоретически что бы не заливать файл "план теракта", а там создать документ Word и просто Ctrl+C -> Ctrl+V ? Узнают или нет?"

Comment: @Vong Корреляционные атаки работают на самом факте передачи траффика.

Comment: @Vong Какие сайты сейчас работают с отключенным JS. googledoc без JS работать не будет

Comment: Так Tor практически без полезен?

Comment: Что бы Вы делали если нужно залить файл максимально анонимно?

Comment: @Vong я бы перестал обсуждать что-то подобное в паблике. Вот вы думаете я про капу шутил?

Comment: Что такое капа?))